# "Make links" moving all selected objects to 1 point

Tags: objects

I really tied found solution but I did't so I post here my question.

I want to optimize my viewport with "Make Limks" Option. 
Problem is when I select all objects that I want to link and applied this option all my objects moves to object that I was linking to.

enter image description here
[image]

[image]

Comment: It is probably because all your objects centers are at the same location. Same data, same center: they overlap once linked. So before linking select them all and use the menu object/transform/origin to geometry.

Comment: Oh that true, thank You I forgot about origins.. Some times source of problem is so obvious so it hard to find first =)